# Does a treaty have to be compatible with the US constitution to be implemented?

Tags: united-states, international, constitutional-law, treaty

What would be the effect of the United States ratifying a treaty that is incompatible with its constitution?

Comment: Some more detail would be good. Some treaties might be clearly unconstitutional (e.g. requiring the government to violate constitutional rights without cause or due process), some might have subtler effects that would not be immediately obvious. Especially in the latter case, there might need to be a court decision to establish it was unconstitutional, although that would require someone to have standing to bring a court case, and it all disappears into legal thickets. So it's possible a treaty could be passed without knowing if it violates the constitution.

Answer (score 7):

> Does a treaty have to be compatible with the US constitution to be
> implemented?

Yes.

A treaty that is incompatible with the U.S. Constitution is void to the extent it is unconstitutional. *See, e.g., Doe v. Braden*, 57 U.S. (16 How.) 635, 657 (1853) ("The treaty is . . . a law made by the proper authority, and the courts of justice have no right to annul or disregard any of its provisions, unless they violate the Constitution of the United States."); *The Cherokee Tobacco*, 78 U.S. (11 Wall.) 616, 620 (1870) ("It need hardly be said that a treaty cannot change the Constitution or be held valid if it be in violation of that instrument."); *De Geofroy v. Riggs*, 133 U.S. 258, 267 (1890) ("It would not be contended that [the treaty power] extends so far as to authorize what the constitution forbids."); *Asakura v. City of Seattle*, 265 U.S. 332, 341 (1924) ("The treaty-making power of the United States . . . does not extend ‘so far as to authorize what the Constitution forbids.’") (quoting *De Geofroy*, 133 U.S. at 267); *Reid v. Covert*, 354 U.S. 1, 16 (1957) ("This Court has regularly and uniformly recognized the supremacy of the Constitution over a treaty.").

Comment: By chance, do you know of any treaties that are still in effect today despite being incompatible with the US constitution, due to necessity?

Comment: @AlanSTACK No. There are no such treaties. There may be treaties that are incompatible with the U.S. Constitution that have not been declared unconstitutional because the manner in which they are unconstitutional involves a hypothetical possibility hasn't presented itself in real life situations, or because the legal process has not yet run its course, but there are no treaties that are in effect despite being incompatible with the U.S. Constitution due to "necessity." That is not a defense against unconstitutionality.

Comment: @ohwilleke: What rules would apply to a treaty which was legitimate when it was ratified if the Constitution were amended in such a fashion as to be incompatible with it?  Suppose, for example, that prior to the Civil War US had ratified a treaty allowing a foreign country to use US ports to transfer slaves between ships?

Comment: @supercat The constitution has absolute precedence over every other form of law.  If an amendment contradicted a treaty, then the incompatible portion of that treaty would have to be discarded or ignored as soon as the amendment took effect.  Whether that invalidates the entire treaty or just a small part of it will depend on the details of that specific treaty.

Comment: What about things like the Berne Convention, which was used to push through modifications to copyright?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse: Are you arguing that the Berne Convention violates the U.S. Constitution? If so, why do you think it does? Or if you don't think it violates the Constitution, why would the Berne Convention be relevant here?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the US modified its statutory law to implement the provisions of the Berne convention.  There's no "pushing through": the executive signed the convention, the senate ratified it, congress passed a bill changing copyright law, and the president signed it.  The legislative and executive branches could have made these changes without signing the treaty.  Acceding to the treaty increases protection for the works of US authors outside the US, though, which is no doubt why they did it.

Comment: @bta: If the Constitution were amended in a manner that made explicit reference to a treaty (e.g. "Slavery is prohibited in all US territories and waters, any contrary treaty provisions notwithstanding"), such language would give the amendment unambiguous superiority over any treaties.  Absent such language, I think a country that wanted the US to continue honoring the treaty could argue that if the people writing the amendment wanted to void the treaty they could have written it to do so, and their failure to do so should be interpreted as an intention to limit the amendment's application...

Comment: ...as necessary to avoid breaching any treaties that were legitimately ratified prior to it [e.g. by carving out of the region in which the Constitution is the Supreme Law of the Land a small corridor connecting docked foreign ships].  Of course, if the hypothetical treaty had existed, the drafters of the Thirteenth Amendment could have (and likely would have) made their intentions clear by unambiguously specifying that the amendment negates any treaty provisions that would be contrary to its intention, or that the US would still be required to do whatever is needed to uphold the treaty.

Comment: @supercat "What rules would apply to a treaty which was legitimate when it was ratified if the Constitution were amended in such a fashion as to be incompatible with it? Suppose, for example, that prior to the Civil War US had ratified a treaty allowing a foreign country to use US ports to transfer slaves between ships?" The treaty would be void. It isn't necessary for the invalidation to be present at the time the treaty is adopted.

Comment: @supercat "I think a country that wanted the US to continue honoring the treaty could argue that if the people writing the amendment wanted to void the treaty they could have written it to do so, and their failure to do so should be interpreted as an intention to limit the amendment's application." This is an unambiguously losing argument in U.S. law. it isn't necessary for the invalidation to be expressly stated.

Comment: @ohwilleke: If there would exist a course of action which would be consistent both with the Constitution as amended and an existing treaty, I would think there should be a strong presumption that the treaty should be upheld in such a case, even if the course of action would be awkward.

Comment: @supercat That is an argument that the treaty doesn't violate the constitution, not an argument that the treaty was valid because it was valid when it as adopted.